# swift read text file and store in string

Tags: swift

I have a text file. It contain only "hello" word but the comparison doesn't work correctly. I think the problem is the reading variable because I tried insiate string contains hello and it works.

```
do {
    readStringProject = try String(contentsOfFile: fileURLProject!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
} catch let error as NSError {
    print("Failed reading from URL: \(fileURL), Error: " + error.localizedDescription)
}
var st: String!
st = "hello"

let st1 : String!
st1 = String (readStringProject)
if st1 == st {
    print("same")
} else {
    print("not same")
}
```

Comment: Have you tried printing `st1`, to see what it actually holds? Or to inspect it's value from the debugger?

Comment: Most probably, the string read from the file contains a trailing newline character.

Comment: I checked it but it doesn't contain trailing newline character.

Comment: I prtinted it contains hello word  same as st

Comment: @Cassy: What does `print(readStringProject.debugDescription)` print?

Comment: it prints "hello\n"
how can I remove newline character?